# fulltext search results showing where most repeated words

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search

I inserted in my web browser and it works great, but it shows me messy results, I would like to show me at the top where over the word or words in the search is repeated.

I looked online tutorials but I can not do it and always come messy, do not understand why.

Right now I have it like this:

```
$sql="SELECT art,tit,tem,cred,info,que,ano,url 
FROM contenido
WHERE MATCH (art,tit,tem,cred,info) 
AGAINST ('" .$busqueda. "' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
ORDER BY id DESC";
```

There is not much information on the Internet about refine or optimize searches for Mysql FULLTEXT. See if experts come through here and so we all learn.

How could refine your search? Thank you.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding the problem "messy results".  Can you post a sample of what you're query is returning and a sample of what you would like it to resemble?

Comment: Sorry if I have spelled wrong, I'm Spanish and my English is limited. What I would like for example is that by pursuing such as "Mercedes Benz", I quit at the top rows of the database where more repeat that word, that is, by relevance. I would also like him to do the search with two words together Mercedes + Benz. Now the search is performed by searching both words together as well as apart. I do not know if I explained well.

Comment: Just to get this out of the way, don't do variable substitution like you're doing, use prepared statements.  Nothing to do with your question but important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is that you're sorting by the `id`.

The fulltext sorts by the match score it calculates, showing stronger matches first.  When you apply  `ORDER BY id DESC`, you loose this sort-by-match ordering.

You can see the actual score in your result set if you want by:

```
SELECT art,tit,tem,cred,info,que,ano,url,
      MATCH (art,tit,tem,cred,info) 
      AGAINST ('your term' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score
FROM contenido
WHERE MATCH (art,tit,tem,cred,info) 
  AGAINST ('your term' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
   ORDER BY id DESC
```

BTW: Use prepared statements for the *'your term'* portion.

If your search string has spaces but each term matter, you need to treat them as separate pieces. So if it's important to have BOTH "Mercedes" AND "Benz":

- Don't: `AGAINST ('Mercedes Benz' IN BOOLEAN MODE)` <--- This means either Mercedes *or* Benz
- Do: `AGAINST ('+Mercedes +Benz' IN BOOLEAN MODE)`

If you want to have anything that must have the first term, but optionally the second term (ranking higher when both found) do:

```
 AGAINST ('+Mercedes Benz' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Here's a long list of combinations: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-boolean.html

AND dont forget, get rid of the `ORDER BY id DESC`.  I think you're final query should look something like this for "Mercedes Benz"

```
SELECT art,tit,tem,cred,info,que,ano,url
    FROM contenido
 WHERE MATCH (art,tit,tem,cred,info) 
  AGAINST ('+Mercedes Benz' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

Yep, freetext in MySQL has a lot of quirks, but play around, you'll get the hang of it.

Comment: Pardon the ignorance, but is there to create a field in the table called score? What features? Thanks, I'll try.

Comment: @PlayerWet The match in your select statement (not the where clause one) adds the score to your result set.

Comment: Ray forgive, I feel stupid now. I tried but I would like him to show at the top where more words are repeated. I used your example and shown in the first positions records containing the word only once. It is very curious. :O

Comment: "SELECT art,tit,tem,cred,info,que,ano,url 

FROM contenido
WHERE MATCH (art,tit,tem,cred,info) 
AGAINST ('+" .$busqueda. "' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 

ORDER BY score DESC"

I created a column named score in the database do not know if this is correct.

Comment: @PlayerWet  you don't need to order by score, the fultext search does it for you.  The score in the select was just for you to see it.

Comment: Oh sorry, I make a mess with the language, I understand you now lol. I'll try and tell you now.

Comment: Thank you very much Ray, you're the best !!